# How to Access Session ID through JQuery

Tags: jquery, session, jquery-cookie

I have a requirement which says get the session ID along with other page details and send to server through ajax ...but i stuck with the session ID [JSESSIONID] ... can you guys give me some idea about fetching  this Session ID ? Am not professional in Jquery ..but intermediate ..

Thanks in advance 
Ravi Tom

Comment: The session id should be sent to the server automatically with any requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

`mySessionId= '<%=Session.SessionID%>';`

no jQuery is needed here.

(You cannot access the session cookie because it is by default set to HTTPOnly)

Comment: From a security standpoint, this is probably not a good idea since it could open you up to session hijacking attacks. The session cookie is HTTPOnly for a reason..

Comment: @JasonP I agree. that's why you cant access it from JS. but I merely answered his question. nothing more nothing less.

Comment: I understand, I just like to try to make people aware of the caveats of solutions that are potentially dangerous.